# Blender Normal baking with & without cage not working

Tags: modeling, texturing, normal-map

Recently I designed a can to use in my game. It is extremely High-Poly and it has a subdiv modifier with 2x subdivisions. Because a model (especially a prop such as a can) would be extremely inefficient in a game space with a large polygon count (tens of thousands), I decided to bake my normals to a lower poly mesh, with only a few hundred polygons. Initially I attempted to bake to a model without a 'cage' and it was off as the normals were not accurate and did not feel realistic. Then I attempted with a cage and had the same look and issue

[image]

^^^This is the High poly initial model (with a 2x on subdivision surface).

[image]

^^^High Poly Model Preview

[image]

^^^ This is the Low Poly model

[image]

^^^This is how it bakes without a cage (I turned up the ray distance a little but it is still an issue when at zero). However with the cage it looks exactly the same, it looks ugly and weird

I have tried all these things and none of them have seemed to achieve a relaistic clean result so I can have the detail but maintain efficiency without my computer spontaneously combusting when I interact and see this object in game. I will provide the model link here if needed, which you can use for getting a clearer view of the problem.

I'm slightly stuck for ideas at this point so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Model [image]

Thanks!

Edit: here is your fixed versison when I download into 2.91.3
[image]

Comment: In addition to @moonboots answer below your normal map image is 2048x2048 but due to the large cylinder much of that image space is wasted and you will see pixelation on the surface. Also you may want to scale up your high poly slightly since the low poly mesh intersects through the high poly near the top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First apply the scale, and lower down the bake *Extrusion* value down to 0.1 (more in your last version). Now you need to select your low-poly object, right click > *Shade Smooth*, also in the *Object Data panel > Normals > Auto Smooth*. Select the high-poly, shift select the low-poly, bake. Lower the *Normal Map* node strength value down to 1. Result:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks but still a similar issue. It's a little better but no real difference

Comment: mmh it fixes the problem for me, could you please share your file again, with all the changes you've made?

Comment: May you send a screenshot of what your result is first just to see what the fix does on your side?

Comment: Here is my file with the changes applied https://blend-exchange.com/b/2992gjSS/

Comment: Yes it works fine for me with your current file, I've edited my answer, you also need to apply the scale and invert the normals even though this was not the problem here, maybe you've have skipped a step, or try with another version of Blender?

Comment: Did you apply the subdivision surface?

Comment: Are you talking about the high-poly Subdivision Surface modifier? No, I didn't, it wouldn't change anything

Comment: By the way your new low-poly is much smaller now so you need to either adjust the scales of your cans in Edit mode or increase the Extrusion value, but it is still not the problem here

Comment: May you share your fixed version. Also what version are you using?

Comment: Is that photo of the high poly or low poly mesh. Because on the download the ridges/divits look nowhere near as realistic as my viewport, even in render mode

Comment: it's a picture of the low-poly with the normal map, I've shared the file

Comment: what version of blender are you on? I'll show a picture of the normals on my download of your fixed file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135498/discussion-between-moonboots-and-cgi-demon402).

Comment: Sorry to disturb you again. I have another issue I added some more to the mesh and the bake isn't working again. Here is the issue blend-exchange.com/b/N8VogLzE. It is not baking all details and there is errors.
If you manage to fix please share on blend exchange, sorry fo hassling you im not good at texture baking :(

Comment: it works fine, pay attention to the objects you select, first select Mesh HighPoly, then shift select Mesh LowPoly.001, bake